# Git merge not display changes

Tags: git, github

I have two branches A and B when i do git merge from B to A is does not shows any changes. Even there are multiple changes are there.

But when i do A to B it shows changes. But my requirement is to merge B to A.

Comment: Can you give more details on how your two branches are related exactly, e.g. by providing a `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, shortened of the relevant commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit all needed changes in both branches `git add .; git commit -m "message"`. Then you do `git checkout A` and `git merge B`.

When you do not see changes you have nothing committed to B, even if you have a change committed to A. B is behind in this case and will not merge.

When you do `git checkout B; git merge A` and you see changes, then you have something committed to A but not to B, like said above. I tested this locally and this matches your situation.

One error which comes to mind is when you do a `git checkout A; git add .`. Then all your changes will be in A, when you change to B you have nothing left to commit, so all the changes are already in A.

You can test this as follows:

```
mkdir gittest
cd gittest    
git init                            
touch readme
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git branch A                                  
git branch B
git checkout A
touch a     
git add a     
git commit -m "a"
git merge B # does not work
git checkout B   
git merge A # does work
touch b          
git add b  
git commit -m "b"
git checkout A   
git merge B # does work now
```